# Invoke-command and run commands with administrator account

Tags: windows-7, powershell

With the following command, I am trying to run `dir c:` with the administrator account from a powershell

```
$RemoteMachine = "10.1.1.40"
$Username = 'Administrator'
$Password = ' '
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username,$pass
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $RemoteMachine -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock { dir c: }
```

However, the output is:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> C:\Users\user\Desktop\anydesk.ps1

PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

That means, it has not connected to the remote machine. I have to say that administrator account is enabled and the remote desktop allows administrator. Any idea to fix that? If I use a normal user, the am able to see the output of `dir c:`.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the password for `Administrator` on the remote machine actually blank?

Try doing each step manually to verify what does and does not work:

```
# Get-Credential will prompt for a username and password
# Try and use the computer *name* instead of the IP:
$RemoteMachine = 'MyPC'
$cred = Get-Credential -UserName "$RemoteMachine\Administrator"

# Use a remote Powershell session instead of invoke-command for troubleshooting:
Enter-PSSession $RemoteMachine -Credential $cred

# In the remote session, manually run "dir C:/"
[MyPC]: PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> dir C:/
```

Then add the results and/or error messages to your question

If the above works, try the following - it's not much different from what you tried earlier:

```
$computername = 'MyPC'
$user = "$computername\Administrator"
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText (Read-Host "MyPassword") -Force
$cred = [PSCredential]::new($user, $password)
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computername -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {Get-ChildItem c:}
```

I want to add that leaving your admin password in plaintext in the script is a bad idea. Please consider storing it somewhere more secure, or use something like the [CredentialManager](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/CredentialManager/2.0) powershell module.

Comment: Yes, I can do that. Is it possible to automate that in the main script? Otherwise that will be an interactive task.

Comment: @mahmood added a suggestion for the main script

Comment: Do you mean `{Get-ChildItem dir c:}`?

Comment: @mahmood sorry for the confusion - in powershell, `dir` is just an alias for `Get-ChildItem`. You can see this with `Get-Command dir`

Comment: You can also pass in the password from the execution process as the first argument and then reference that as `$password = $args[0];` in your script which is just as secure. You just pass in the password value (e.g. `C:\scripts\PSScript.ps1 "password123"`) at execution time so it's also not stored in the script. This way may be more flexible for others than using Credential Manager. Another example is `Powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& 'C:\scripts\psscript.ps1' 'password123456'"` to be more explicit with another PS execution example.